# Android getting spinner to change contentview

Tags: android, spinner

Yet another problem :/

Here's my spinner code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class mobs extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mobsspinner);

    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.mobsselect, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);

    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View     selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            setContentView(R.layout.id);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });



}

}
```

I want to be able to put the content from a separate xml file with some context.
The content should be placed underneath the spinner.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to put a different view from code, below the Spinner?

If that's the case you should put an ID to the LinearLayout parent of your Spinner,  and then inflate a new layout/view and attach it to the LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout" >

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then from your code

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, ll, false);
ll.addView(v);
```